# How to have the abstract and introduction on the same page in IEEETran format?

Tags: page-breaking, ieeetran, abstract, gap

I am using ieeetran format for an article. It makes a break between the abstract and the rest of the paper. How I can remove that gap?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\DeclareMathOperator{\std}{\mathrm{std}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\newcommand\pdfstrutmc[3][\strut ]%
{
  \pdfmarkupcomment{#1#2}{#3}%
}
\usepackage[draft]{todonotes}   % notes showed



\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
 
\fi
  
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother





% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

% ----------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawCoordinateGrid}{O{} m m m m m m}{%
    \def\XGridMin{#2}
    \def\XGridMax{#3}
    \def\YGridMin{#4}
    \def\YGridMax{#5}
    \def\ZGridMin{#6}
    \def\ZGridMax{#7}
    %
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0, thick, black]
      \draw [#1] (\XGridMin,\YGridMin) grid (\XGridMax,\YGridMax);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0, thick, black]
      \draw [#1] (\YGridMin,\ZGridMin) grid (\YGridMax,\ZGridMax);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0, thick, black]
      \draw [#1] (\XGridMin,\ZGridMin) grid (\XGridMax,\ZGridMax);
    \end{scope}
}%


\begin{document}
% \frontmatter          % for the preliminaries
%
% \pagestyle{fancy}  % switches on printing of running heads
% \addtocmark{} % additional mark in the TOC

% \mainmatter              % start of 
%
\title{My title }


\author[1]{aaa~aaa}
\author[2]{bbb~bbb}


\affil[1]{xxx}
\affil[2]{yyy}

\affil[ ]{\textit {fbf@bfg.nl}}



\begin{abstract}
   here the abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

Intro!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you submitting to IEEE?  If so, don't try to adjust the page breaks; their document class has the breaks where they want them.  If not, then don't use IEEEtran.

Comment: Off-topic: do you really need all packages those packages? Some of them you load twice, some of them are deprecated, loading order is wrong (hyperref should be loaded last)  ...

Comment: I am going to upload that on arxiv.org. So I need to fix that.
Sorry, I am a Latex user, I am not very professional in recognizing the best packages for my paper. I added them on demand while I was writing the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Very easily, actually. In your MWE, simply write:

```
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
   here the abstract
\end{abstract}
```

Or, to be clear, `\maketitle` has to go *before* the `abstract` environment, otherwise the title would be put in a new page *after* the abstract (as in your MWE).